# Laravel eloquent multiple where clause doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I used the following code to add multiple where clause but it doesn't work,

```
$matchThese = ['sale_date' => $aravaitaken_date,'purchase_number' => $purchase_number];

$aravaitaken_total_moottai = DB::table('take_aravais')->where($matchThese)->sum("moottai");
$aravaitaken_total_kuvintal = DB::table('take_aravais')->Where($matchThese)->sum("kuvintal");
```

I am new to laravel and i request you to give a better solution than making it as duplicate or negative.. If there is any minor mistakes notify me the changes need to do.. and my complete code was

```
public function getAravaiTotalbyDate(Request $request){

        $input = $request->all();
        $aravaitaken_date = $input['aravaitaken_date'];
    $purchase_number = $input['purchase_number'];

        $aravaitaken_date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($aravaitaken_date));


$matchThese = ['sale_date' => $aravaitaken_date,'purchase_number' => $purchase_number];

    $aravaitaken_total_moottai = DB::table('take_aravais')->where($matchThese)->sum("moottai");
    $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal = DB::table('take_aravais')->Where($matchThese)->sum("kuvintal");


        $id = Settings::all()->last()->id;
        $percentage = Settings::findOrFail($id);
        $percentage_rice = $percentage->rice_percentage;
        $percentage_kurunai = $percentage->kurunai_percentage;
        $percentage_thavudu = $percentage->thavudu_percentage;

        $aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal = $percentage_rice * $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal / 100;
        $aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_kurunai = $percentage_kurunai * $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal / 100;
        $aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_thavudu = $percentage_thavudu * $aravaitaken_total_kuvintal / 100;

        return view('Purchase.calculation', compact('percentage', 'aravaitaken_total_moottai', 'aravaitaken_total_kuvintal', 'aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal', 'aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_kurunai', 'aravu_seithathil_varavu_total_kuvintal_thavudu'));

    }
```

And the AJAX code that i used was,

```
$( function() {
    var aravaitaken_date = $('#aravaitaken_date').val();
    var purchase_number = $('#purchase_number').val();
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "getAravaiTotalbyDate",
        type: "POST",
        data: { aravaitaken_date: aravaitaken_date, purchase_number: purchase_number },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('.calculation').html("<div class='row'><div class='col-md-12 text-center'><br/><br/><br/><br/><img src='images/ajax-loader.gif'/></div></div>");
        },
        success: function(data){
            $('.calculation').html(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Any help that solve my problem would be appreciable..

Comment: pls use different `$matchThese` name, you area actually replacing the variables.. also, *Here when i select a date, a purchase number will come and when i click on the number the details regarding that number will be displayed* is pretty vague, is it require to send some parameter back, or you'll print it all through php..?

Comment: Using like this is correct or not??  $matchThese = ['sale_date' => $aravaitaken_date,'purchase_number' => $purchase_number];

Comment: you can do that, but it will generate a query like `WHERE sale_date = $aravaitake_date AND purchase_number = $purchase_number` (simplified).

Comment: I have a date selection, when i select a date , the purchase numbers on that date will be displayed , i have already stored some data in those purchase numbers respectively, when i select a purchase number, the details regarding that purchase number need to come.. Now it is coming as sum of the details added on that date.. but i need the details on that number should get printed..

Comment: Hi @ManiRaj, do you have any web programming experience.. since.. *select a date* --> then the purchase numbers for that date *displayed* -- this, how did you achieve this? Ajax..? or bring the user to another page? since, the purchase number available once date selected.. as far as i read your code, its linear, it assumes that it have date and the purchase number.. cmiiw

Comment: No i don't have programming experience i am web designer and now only enter into programming but learnt basics of laravel.. This was achieved by using AJAX.. Also i have added ajax that i used..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143861/discussion-between-mani-raj-and-bagus-tesa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Model::table('take_aravais')->where('sale_date', '=',$aravaitaken_date)->where('purchase_number','=', $purchase_number)->sum("moottai");
```

Comment: It is throwing this error :

FatalThrowableError in PurchaseController.php line 171:
Call to a member function get() on integer

Comment: I think the code should be like this 'sale_date' , '=', $aravaitaken_date .. The equal to be like this i think because it is showing error..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143862/discussion-between-mani-raj-and-exprator).

Answer (score 0):

```
DB::table('take_aravais')->where('sale_date', '=',$aravaitaken_date)->where('purchase_number','=', $purchase_number)->sum("moottai");
```

Try this